# Fetch the Storage Key of a Storage account using Service Principal in Azure (Access Token)

Tags: azure, rest, curl, azure-storage-account

Is there any way I can fetch the storage key of a storage account using an access token. We are using AAD authentication for the storage account and we have a client id and secret. We generated access token with client id and secret. Please help

Regards,
John

I was trying to use curl and REST API calls, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and include: 1) Request details with CURL/REST API call and 2) Azure RBAC role your service principal has on the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

> Fetch the Storage Key of a Storage account using Service Principal in Azure (Access Token)

You can follow the below method to get the list of keys of Azure blob storage using curl request.

> Note: According to [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal#assign-an-azure-role) the application need atleast **`Reader`** role to list the keys.

First, you need to fetch the access token using the below request.

**Request:**

```
curl -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token \
-d grant_type=client_credentials \
-d client_id={client-id} \
-d client_secret={client-secret} \
-d resource=https://management.azure.com/
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now you can use the access token to list keys.

**Request:**

```
 curl -X POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/susbscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourcegrpname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname/listKeys?api-version=2023-01-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer  < Your-Access-token >" -H "Content-Length: 0" | jq
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Storage Accounts - List Keys - REST API (Azure Storage Resource Provider) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/list-keys?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Thank you venkatesan for the reply. But the service principal we have is only for the resource 'storage-account'. We don't have it for 'management.azure.com' and the access token can only be generated for storage account. Hence the rest api for generating the storage account using access token wont work in our case.

Comment: Hi @John How are you generating access token in your case?

Comment: We have the client id and secret for storage account and we use that to generate the access key using the below curl Command  "                                     
                                                                                
 curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=***&client_secret=***&resource=https://storageaccount.windows.net' https://login.microsoftonline.com/**/oauth2/token)"